# Unable to create one-to-one relationship between entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

**Update 1:** Added a link to the code for the entity classes.

I have a `Vehicle` entity (to hold information about a vehicle) and an
`UploadedDocument` entity (represents any uploaded document, in this case (say) the registration papers) being stored in the DB in separate tables (other entities may also need to store uploaded documents).  There is a one-to-one correspondence between these.

Mapping:

```
<class name="Vehicle" table="Vehicles" lazy="true">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="License" />
  <property name="ManufactureYear" />
  <property name="PurchaseYear" />
  <one-to-one name="Registration" class="UploadedDocument" />
</class>

<class name="UploadedDocument" table="UploadedDocuments" lazy="true">
  <id name="ID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <property name="Data" length="2147483647"  />
  <many-to-one name="SupplierCustomer" class="SupplierCustomer" column="SupplierCustomerID" />
</class>
```

The code for the [`Vehicle` and `UploadedDocument` classes](http://pastebin.com/HVZuqNbh).  This is what the code for saving these classes looks like:

```
using (ISession sess = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    sess.Save(uploadedDoc);
    vehicleToAdd.Registration = uploadedDoc;
    sess.Save(vehicleToAdd);
}
```

Things don't work as I expect them to: NHibernate doesn't add an ID field for
the `UploadedDocument` to the `Vehicles` table and there's therefore no
one-to-one relationship.

If I simply change my `<one-to-one>` mapping to `<many-to-one
name="Registration" class="UploadedDocument" column="RegistrationID" />` in the `Vehicle.hbm.xml` file, I can get things to work, but I don't need
bi-directional mapping or many-to-one.  Just plain, simple one-to-one mapping
where a `RegistrationID` column appears in the `Vehicles` table.  Does
NHibernate provide no simple way to create a one-to-one relationship between
`Vehicle` and `UploadedDocument`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct way to do this: use a `<many-to-one>` mapping with an added `unique` constraint:

```
<many-to-one name="Registration" class="UploadedDocument"
    column="RegistrationID" unique="true" />
```

For further reference: [5.1.12. one-to-one](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a foreign key in your `<one-to-one>` tag, otherwise, NHibernate connects the two entities by their IDs. 
If you want to connect the main entity(Vehicle) by a cretain column to another entity by its ID you need to add foreign-key attribute and declare the connecting column.

```
<one-to-one name="Registration" class="UploadedDocument" foreign-key="RegistrationID" />
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't add the `RegistrationID` column